# AWS SDK .NET DynamoDB ASYNC

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-net

I am trying to use AWS SDK for .NET Core.

- Create a table to count views on videos.
- Add a view count for a day.
- Increment existing count for a day.
- Query for video counts between two dates for a video.

.NET Core AWS SDK uses Async methods which are not documented in AWS. There is a feature request on their github page for this to happen.... but it is dated from last year. (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/787)

CREATE THE TABLE

This works and creates a table on the AWS Console.

```
var ctRequest = new CreateTableRequest
{
    AttributeDefinitions = new List<AttributeDefinition>()
    {
        new AttributeDefinition
        {
            AttributeName = "ViewUid",
            AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
        },
        new AttributeDefinition
        {
            AttributeName = "ViewDate",
            AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S
        }
    },
    KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement>
    {
        new KeySchemaElement
        {
            AttributeName = "ViewUid",
            KeyType = KeyType.HASH //Partition key
        },
        new KeySchemaElement
        {
            AttributeName = "ViewDate",
            KeyType = KeyType.RANGE
        }
    },
    ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput
    {
        ReadCapacityUnits = 5,
        WriteCapacityUnits = 6
    },
    TableName = _settings.AWSDynamoDBViewCountTable
};

var response = _client.CreateTableAsync(ctRequest).Result;
```

UPDATE AND ITEM WITH AUTO-INCREMENT A FIELD

This, sadly, is where i hit issues. The old docs are found here under the Atomic Counter section. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetItemCRUD.html)

> Invalid ConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: \"SET\", near: \"SET
>   VC\"

```
var viewData = new Document();
viewData["ViewUid"] = videoUid; //Table entry UID
viewData["VideoId"] = videoId;  // Video ID
viewData["ViewDate"] = date;
viewData["ViewCount"] = 0;
//Document result = await _viewCountTable.PutItemAsync(viewData);

Expression expr = new Expression();
expr.ExpressionStatement = "SET #VC = #VC + :val";
expr.ExpressionAttributeValues[":val"] = 1;
expr.ExpressionAttributeNames["#VC"] = "ViewCount";
var updateConfig = new UpdateItemOperationConfig() { 
    ConditionalExpression = expr,
    ReturnValues = ReturnValues.UpdatedNewAttributes
};

var result = await _viewCountTable.UpdateItemAsync(viewData, updateConfig);
return result;
```

QUERY FOR DATE RANGE

Get one video's view count for a date range.

```
string queryTimeSpanStartString = dateFrom.ToString(AWSSDKUtils.ISO8601DateFormat);
string queryTimeSpanEndString = dateTo.ToString(AWSSDKUtils.ISO8601DateFormat);
var request = new QueryRequest
{
    TableName = _settings.AWSDynamoDBViewCountTable,
    KeyConditions = new Dictionary<string, Condition>()
    {
        {
            "VideoId",  new Condition()
            {
                ComparisonOperator = "EQ",
                AttributeValueList = new List<AttributeValue>()
                {
                    new AttributeValue { S = videoId }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "ViewDate",
            new Condition
            {
                ComparisonOperator = "BETWEEN",
                AttributeValueList = new List<AttributeValue>()
                {
                    new AttributeValue { S = queryTimeSpanStartString },
                    new AttributeValue { S = queryTimeSpanEndString }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var response = await _client.QueryAsync(request);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to update the ViewCount with the following code:

string tableName = "videos";

```
        var request = new UpdateItemRequest
        {
            Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>() { { "ViewUid", new AttributeValue { S = "replaceVideoIdhere" } } },
            ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"#Q", "ViewCount"}
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
            {
                {":incr", new AttributeValue {N = "1"}}
            },
            UpdateExpression = "SET #Q = #Q + :incr",
            TableName = tableName
        };

        var response = await _dynamoDbClient.UpdateItemAsync(request);
```

I created a table called "videos" with a partition key named "ViewUid" as string. Let me know if this works for you.